# How can I reuse expensive widget across the app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using `google_maps_flutter` to embed a map in my flutter application. This widget is expensive to create, (loading map tiles take some time) so I want to initialize this widget once, keep its state, and re-use it across the lifecycle of the user activity.

```
Key googleMapKey = GlobalKey();

....

GoogleMap(
   key: googleMapKey,
   mapType: MapType.normal,
   initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng),
   onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
     print("Map has been initialized");
     ....
   }
   ...
)
```

What I have tried so far is assigning GlobalKey() to this widget so that the widget can be re-parented when necessary. I made sure that one GlobalKey() is used across different pages.

In my app, list of restaurants are shown in a list view. When user taps on one of the list items, detail page opens up, and above GoogleMap widget loads in addition to other restaurant details.

However, it appears that when user go backs to the previous list page, and the tap on another list item to open up a detail page of another restaurant, `GoogleMap` seems to be re-initialized, because I am seeing "Map has been initialized" text shown again.

I do see following snippet from the flutter doc for [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) although I am not sure if that is the reason.

> Widgets that have global keys reparent their subtrees when they are moved from one location in the tree to another location in the tree. In order to reparent its subtree, a widget **must arrive at its new location in the tree in the same animation frame** in which it was removed from its old location in the tree.

What is the correct way to use GlobalKey for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, I can't find anyone that knows the official answer.

The only way I know to avoid the rebuild is to use globalKey.currentWidget in the secondary location for the moved widget.

If you have a better solution, let me know.